# How can I pivot a really large dataframe using dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a Dask dataframe that I load like this:

```py
dates_devices = dd.read_csv('data_part*.csv.gz', compression='gzip', blocksize=None) 
dates_devices['cnt'] = 1
dates_devices.astype({'cnt': 'uint8'}).dtypes # make it smaller
```

I'm trying to use dask to pivot the table:

```py
final_table = (dates_devices
               .categorize(columns=['date'])
               .pivot_table(index='device', 
                            columns='date', 
                            values='cnt').fillna(0).astype('uint8'))
```

That "runs" just fine, but when I do the implicit compute in the `dd.to_parquet()` I get:

`MemoryError: Unable to allocate 5.42 GiB for an array with shape (727304656,) and data type uint8`,

then taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type), I tried

```sh
`$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`
```

but the kernel still gets killed. I've 32GB RAM, and 32GB swap on Linux Xubuntu, so that should fit comfortably in RAM. Is there a way to do this or to "test" why exactly I'm getting my kernel killed?

Answer (score 1):

You can can try writing your dask dataframes in chunks to overcome the memory limitation: For example:

```
for i in range(final_table.npartitions):
    partition = final_table.get_partition(i)`
```

Please see how I do `.to_sql` -- you can take a similar approach with `.to_parquet`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458085/6366770